# How to trigger maximize/minimize in windows programming

Tags: c++, windows, winforms

For windows programming in C++, how to make active window to either maximize or minimize?

For mouse down events we use something like `mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN` and send it to the system using `SendInput()` function. I assume these are defined in windows.h.

How to achieve the maximize or minimize on these lines?

Comment: As an aside, see the policy on signatures here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 3):

Use the [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, with either SW_MAXIMIZE or SW_MINIMIZE.

Comment: So how to get the handle to any window on the screen ?

Comment: or rather the active/foreground window on the screen and can we call this function explicitly?

Comment: It's generally considered rude for a program to minimize the windows of other applications. What if the user wanted that other window kept open?

Comment: @ Raymond : that is the requirement

Comment: What requires your program to be rude?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the foreground window with this code:

```
#include <windows.h>
HWND foregroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();
```

and then minimize the foreground window using foregroundWindow as handle

```
ShowWindow(foregroundWindow, SW_MINIMIZE);
```

or maximize it

```
ShowWindow(foregroundWindow, SW_MAXIMIZE);
```

But I don't know how to know other windows' handle, you can google it or ask here in StackOverflow how to get windows by its process name or by PID.