# How can I control application window behavior in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, controls

I have an idea for a small Windows utility. The issue I am having is figuring out what you use to manipulate application window behavior. e.g., minimize, maximize, etc.

What should I be looking into?

Comment: For minimize/maximize: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275393

Comment: *... the most common or is the language (most) used to program Windows applications.*  I see you haven't heard of [C#](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1484233174) yet.

Comment: I have. My statement was based on Googling, what is the most common programming language used for windows applications. The answer was C++

Comment: You could use C# or Java.  The C# languages has facilities built in to assist in developing GUI applications on Windows.  Java comes with GUI elements.  There may also be other languages as well.

Comment: "I have. My statement was based on Googling, what is the most common programming language used for windows applications. The answer was C++" - you have to know that Google sometimes lies to you. C# and its several UI frameworks exist for **over two decades**. C++ isn't the main win-app-developing-language at least for a decade or more. Mostly due to those UI frameworks. Yes, you can use them in so-called "managed C++", but it's not "the C++" newbies have in mind when saying "C++". Improve your google-fu. Read more. Be more critical about what internet tells you on the front page.

Comment: And yes, of course, anything you can do in C# you can also do in C++. That's given. It may even happen that writing your app in C++ may not be that much harder than writing it in C#. However, when maintenance, future changes & installations/updates, and finally, glorius bug hunting begins, you may suddenly discover that all of that is **much** harder when you write a native C++ app than any managed c#/c++ app. If yo unever did it before, start with managed langage (C#, F#, C++, whatever), seriously.

Comment: see, your this answer is extremely helpful and you dont come off sounding like a complete mook. thank you again.  @DrewDormann if you would like to submit your response as an answer, i would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Thanks :) Anyway, finishing - regarding things like maximize/minimize -- that's.. complicated. It depends in 100% on the UI framework you choose. All of them do it in a similar way, but different, and if you pick one framework and try using solution from another - it will just not compile at best. For example, [in WPF](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.windowstate?view=net-5.0) and [in WinForms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate?view=net-5.0) - both are properties, both are on 'window' component - but not identical

Comment: @MartyLavender I'm glad that link answered your question.  As is typically done here, I will mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks  I appreciate it.   I think it was more so an issue of not knowing what to correctly search for. The answer was obviously there. But I do appreciate your help.